# Reference a resource from within another resource file

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource, infragistics, resx

We have a C# .Net solution with over 60 projects that we are starting to globalise/localise . I have a top level resx file with a variety of common strings to use everywhere. Lower down I have resx files with tooltip info etc that we will eventually localise. I want to take some string values from the top level resx and place them within some of the tooltip strings.

The tooltips are Infragistics if it helps, but I think this is really a resx issue, and it's not just tooltips that need this.

In essence, how do I embed a value from one resource file into a larger string inside another resource?